# Using Javascript function argument as elementId

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I know there are loads of questions similar to this, but I can't find the answer I'm looking for among them.

Probably super simple:
I have a very basic JS function, and it has a single argument passed to it. I just want the function to recognise that argument when used in the document.getElementById as the ID.

**HTML**

```
<div id="figure1" onmouseover="popup(figure1)"><div class="hide"> TEST </div></div>
```

**JS Function**

```
<script>
function popup(fig) {
    var setnow = document.getElementById( fig );
    setnow.className = "show";
}
</script>
```

I have tested it without using the argument, i.e.:

```
<script>
function popup() {
    var setnow = document.getElementById("figure1");
    setnow.className = "show";
}
</script>
```

... and it works as expected.

I don't use JS ever, so probably this is very simple. :-)

Comment: Why downvote? If someone asks a stupid question, that makes them novice, not worthy of a downvote...I am not a javascripter, I just needed a little help, and I did look first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the argument:

```
<div id="figure1" onmouseover="popup('figure1')"><div class="hide"> TEST </div></div>
```

Also if you want to get the same element you can use this, then you will not need to use getElementById:

```
<div id="figure1" onmouseover="popup(this)"><div class="hide"> TEST </div></div>
```

```js
function popup(el) {
    el.className = "show";
}
```

Comment: That is correct! Can't believe I didn't test that myself :-) I will mark the answer as correct in 10 mins.

Answer (score 1):

In an eventhandler, you can use this to denote the element:

```
<script>
function popup() {
  this.className = "show";
}
</script>
```